# Where are the git stash elements stored? Is the data structure really a stack?

Tags: git, data-structures, language-agnostic

To understand the git stash better, I would like to know: Where and in what data structure are the elements of the git stash stored? In a stack? In an ordered set?

---

Details:

Every documentation, article and book (except [Git Internals](http://opcode.org/peepcode-git.pdf)) says that the git stash is a **stack**.

Recently, I found out that you can retrieve and delete the elements in arbitrary order from the stash -- what a helpful feature. Because of this feature and [A Hacker's Guide to Git](https://wildlyinaccurate.com/a-hackers-guide-to-git/), it seems to me that the stash rather consists of a **chronologically ordered set of references** somewhere. However, in `.git/refs/stash` only the latest stash element is stored, in form of a merge commit (which also contains the date the stash element was created).

Is there another ([top-secret pre-index stash-cache](https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/still-hatin-on-git-now-with-added-actual-reasons/);) data structure holding all the stash elements? Or does git stash (list|pop|apply) retrieve the elements from its regular object store? How?

So what data structure do the stash elements form? Is the chronological order of the elements implicitly given by the date of the merge commits? If the elements are in fact stored in a stack, how does git retrieve and delete the elements in arbitrary order?

Comment: A stash entry is a commit referred to by refs *stash{n}*. In the manual of `git stash` you could find some clues.

Comment: Thanks, ElpieKay. And where does git internally store the refs stash{n}? I only find the most recent reference in ´.git/refs/stash´.

Comment: Thanks againn, ElpieKay. I now found out that {i} is reflog syntax, and the older stash elements are correspondingly stored in the reflog. I guess I have to read up about the reflog now.... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [ElpieKay wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863293/where-are-the-git-stash-elements-stored-is-the-data-structure-really-a-stack#comment72833436_42863293), all but the *current* stash are stored in the reflog for the *reference* `refs/stash`.  See the definitions of "ref" and "reflog" in [the gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).  Note that branch names like `master` and `develop` are one kind of reference, and are short for the full name `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/develop` respectively.  Tag names are another kind of reference; the tag `v2.2` is really the reference `refs/tags/v2.2`.

Most references are prefixed with `refs/`.  In fact, the various HEADs—`HEAD` itself, and `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on—are the only exceptions, and most of *those* don't *have* reflogs.  `HEAD` is the only one that does.

Normally, reflog entries are simply linearly-numbered: `HEAD@{1}` or `master@{1}` is "the commit to which `HEAD` or `master` pointed before its most recent update", `master@{2}` is the commit two steps ago, and so on.  This is described in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  For convenience, the *current* value can be referred-to with `@{0}`: `master@{0}` and `master` always resolve to the same hash ID.  If the `refs/stash` reference were used in the same way as other references, it would work as a queue, rather than a stack—but it's not *used* that way.  Instead, the `git stash` code explicitly *deletes* early entries.

Since the numbering is always sequential, deleting an entry causes all the *higher* numbers to drop down by one.  If you manually delete `master@{5}`, for instance, then what used to be `master@{6}` is now `master@{5}`, what used to be `master@{7}` is now `master@{6}`, and so on.

Adding a new entry, of course, pushes everything up one.  So when you create a new stash, the one that used to be `stash` aka `stash@{0}` is now `stash@{1}`.  The one that used to be `stash@{1}` is now `stash@{2}`, and so on.  With other reflogs, like `master`, no one calls this "pushing", it's just the ordinary queue in action.

Once you *delete* `stash@{0}` aka `stash`, though, all the higher entries—`stash@{1}`, `stash@{2}`, and so on—drop down by one, so now `stash` has been "popped" and the previous `stash@{1}` is just `stash`.  Of course, you can also `git stash drop stash@{4}` to delete that particular entry, keeping 0-to-3 and renumbering 5-and-up.  Note  that `git stash pop` of any particular stash just means "apply and, if that seems to succeed, drop".

Note, not entirely incidentally, that each reflog entry *also* has a time-stamp attached.  You can write `master@{yesterday}` or `master@{3.hours.ago}` and Git will find the hash ID of the appropriate reflog entry, based on the time stamps.<sup>1</sup>  Because stash identifiers are just reflog entries, this same syntax works there.  (I have never actually found this all that useful anywhere, perhaps because I have no sense of time when I am working and cannot remember what day of the week it is *now*, much less when I did something earlier. :-) )  To go with these time stamps, *most* reflogs *expire*: an old reflog entry will, by default, go away after 90 days, or just 30 days if the object it names is not *reachable* from the current value of the same reference.<sup>2</sup>  However, `refs/stash` itself is exempt from this expiration, by default.  All of this is configurable: see all of the `gc.reflogExpire` settings in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>If you updated the reference several times in a day but not more than once per hour, `@{yesterday}` means `@{24.hours.ago}`.  If you updated more than once per hour, multiply by another 60: `@{1440.minutes.ago}`.  If you updated more than once per minute, multiply by 60 again: `@{86400.seconds.ago}`.  The resolution does not go any finer than that.

<sup>2</sup>This is how Git retains for 30 days, but eventually purges, old commits that were abandoned by a `git rebase`, for instance.  *Reachability* is a key concept provided by the Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG formed by the tags, commits, and tree objects in the repository.  (Blobs are *in* the DAG but have no part in extending it as they are always leaf nodes.  Hence a blob may itself be reachable or unreachable, but it never affects the reachability of any *other* object.)