# Recover git stashes after deleting a local repository

Tags: git

So I had a local copy of a project/repository on my Desktop where i was actively developing code. In that repository, i had multiple stashes that i created using 'git stash' for different purposes. However, I deleted the whole project and it went to my 'trash' bin. Then, i realized that i had some important git stash work in that project that i just deleted.

Is there any way to restore or view those stashes for that repository that i just deleted? I can't seem to find any working/ good answers.

Please help....really need those stashes. Not sure what happened to them after deleting the project copy.

Comment: I hate to suggest this blindingly obvious solution...but can you just pull it out of the trash?

Comment: I did do that but when I open the project on my editor and do git stash list, it is empty. The stash is not there anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you've deleted the `.git` folder associated with the project, you have **no way** of recovering the metadata contained within Git unless you've backed that folder up somewhere else.  Because stashes live solely on your machine, they are more vulnerable to being deleted and irrecoverable in this fashion than if you had a remote repository and pushed that work to a branch.

Comment: The .git folder is still in the project. I pulled it out from trash and the folder still exists. However, the stash is gone. I know stashes are attached to the machine so I'm not sure why it is empty on that recovered project?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can recover the structure from your trash bin, it is gone.

As Makoto pointed out, stashes reside on your local machine within the .git directory. Once the .git directory is deleted, then everything related to that repository is also deleted.

Comment: I got the .git directory back from the project but the stash is gone. I can't seem to find it anywhere inside the .git folder.

Comment: You may want to read through this SO post, but I believe that the stash should have been there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863293/where-are-the-git-stash-elements-stored-is-the-data-structure-really-a-stack#comment72833436_42863293